# "Function failed on loading user code. Error message: You must specify a region." when uploading function through GCF online console

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Within a framework I am building some functions that run on the main Faas providers (aws,gcp,azure,alicloud).  The main function is essentially an elif based on a environment variable deciding which function to call ("do stuff on aws", "do stuff on gcp")etc.  The functions essentially just read from the appropriate database (aws->dynamo, gcp->firestore, azure->cosmos).

When uploading my zip to google cloud functions through their web portal, i get the following error:

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: You must specify a region.
```

I'm concerned it's got something to do with my piplock file, and a clash with the aws dependencies.  Not sure though.  I cannot find anywhere online where someone has had this error message with gcp (certainly not through using the online console), and only see results for this error with aws.

My requirements.txt file is simply:

```
google-cloud-firestore==1.4.0
```

The piplock contains the google requirements, but doesn't state the region anywhere.  However, when using the gcp console, it automatically uploads to us-central1.

Comment: Found the error in a Google Groups.  If anyone else has this problem, it's because you're importing boto and uploading to gcp.  GCP say it's boto's fault.  So you can either split up your code so that you only bring in necessary gcp files, or wrap your imports in if's based on environment vars.

Comment: Can you link to the thread you found?

Comment: It's in a closed Cloud Functions Beta Testers group on google.   If you can get access to the group, the link is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cloud-functions-beta-testers/boto$20error$20python%7Csort:date/cloud-functions-beta-testers/42jJrRKxjk8/7Uu40ZHlAAAJ

Comment: The response from the gcp Product Manager was "Hi all -- closing this out. Turns out this wasn't an issue in Cloud Functions/gcloud. The error was one emitted by the `boto` library: "You must specify a region.". This was confusing because the concept of region applies to AWS and GCP. We're making a tweak to our error message so that this should hopefully be a little more obvious in the future."

Comment: Can you please add this as an answer? I think it would be useful for the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error in a Google Groups. If anyone else has this problem, it's because you're importing boto and uploading to gcp. GCP say it's boto's fault. So you can either split up your code so that you only bring in necessary gcp files, or wrap your imports in if's based on environment vars.

The response from the gcp Product Manager was "Hi all -- closing this out. Turns out this wasn't an issue in Cloud Functions/gcloud. The error was one emitted by the boto library: "You must specify a region.". This was confusing because the concept of region applies to AWS and GCP. We're making a tweak to our error message so that this should hopefully be a little more obvious in the future."